# woocommerce Shipping To Be Confirmed text

Tags: woocommerce

When I goto the cart in woocommerce and I have not provided a shipping address my site displays "To Be Confirmed (Free)". I'm trying to remove the '(Free).' I have hunted through many of the template files and the shipping classes and can't seem to find where to change this.

Any idea where I might look?

Comment: I ended up using Jquery to replace the text. The clumsiest of solutions but it works....